# How do I access the contents of a numpy record in C?

Tags: python, numpy, swig

Suppose I create

```
descriptor = np.dtype([
        ('left', np.double, 3),
        ('center', np.double, 3),
        ('right', np.double, 3),
    ])
value = np.zeros(10, dtype=descriptor)
```

I can verify that `value` is implemented as a contiguous memory of 90 doubles.

Likewise, I can modify `value[3]` and see that the change is reflected in the original array.  So that means that `value[3]` is some sort of data structure that indicates a location in that contiguous memory.

But what exactly is `value[3]`.  If a random `value[i]` is passed to a C function, how can the C code find the data being referred to by that element?  For normal non-record subarrays, you can use the `PyArray_DATA` macro to get the location of the data, even if that data happens to be in the middle of someone bigger array.  I haven't figured out the corresponding thing to use for numpy Records.

The mro() of the created element seems to be:

```
[numpy.record, numpy.void, numpy.flexible, numpy.generic, object]
```

---

Question updated.  I had accidentally switched my variable name from `value` to `x` in the middle of the question.

Note.  I also want to be clear what my question is.  `value` is clearly an array, and it is well documented how to access it in the numpy documentation.  It is less clear what `value[3]` is.  If I pass this to C code, how do I find the 9 memory locations that contain its data.

Comment: `value`, like any array, has a data-buffer, who's values are 'interpreted' according to the dtype.  Since you use `double` in the subdtypes, all values are doubles, as you deduced 90 of them.  So it could be `viewed` is a (90,), or (10,9) or (10,3,3) float array.  `value.view(float).shape` is (90,).

Comment: I believe a numpy record can be 'mapped' onto a `c struct`.  That would be more useful if it contains a mix of dtypes - floats, int, and string.  Regarding c interfacing, judging from other SO questions, `numba` and `cython` are more widely used whan `SWIG` these days.  But I'm more of an observer in these things than a user.

Comment: @hpaulj.  I updated my question to make it clearer what I was asking.  If I write `x = value[3]`, then somewhere inside whatever represents `x` I must have a way of finding its memory locations.  [I don't care about getting the structure per se.  That info already exists in C.]

Comment: `value` and `x` are both numpy arrays.  `x.base` should show `value`.  It shares the underlying `data_buffer`.  I can see that by comparing the `__array_interface__['data']` values.  But I don't think that can be used programmatically.  `memoryview(value)` and `memoryview(x)` give a memoryview object which can be used in places like `np.ndarray`.  From the 'data' values, I can deduce that `x` "starts" 27*8 bytes further into the data_buffer.  But I don't know how to translate those insights into SWIG terms.

Comment: The title is nearly incomprehensible. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `value[3]` to any Python function - including a Python function implemented in C - you are not passing the `value` object and a memory offset - you are passing a reference to separate temporary floating point value. You can access it as if it was any other floating point value.

If you want to access a `numpy` array from C, I suggest you take a look at the buffer protocol in the Python C API documentation.

Or, you can also call the `__getitem__` method from C. This one will work exactly as from Python but it won't be the most efficient way to retrieve a large chunk of the array.

Comment: We're talking records here, not floats/ints.  Modifying an element of v[3] clearly modifies the original array.   The same way that for a 2-dimensional array, I can grab x[3], modifying an element of it, and it modifies the original array.  I'm trying to understand what a Record is, and how it points to its data.

Comment: If you want to modify a numpy array, then your best bet is either the buffer protocol - which is very efficient but hard to use - either calling the Python `__setitem__` method which will take care of finding the offset and size of the element but will be less efficient if modifying a large number of elements.

Comment: If going for the buffer protocol, do not forget that numpy arrays can go backwards and sideways.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the answer.  It appears that numpy records satisfy the [array interface](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.interface.html).  In Python, information about the array can be gotten by looking at the `__array_interface__` field of the `record`.

In C code, I can do:

```
    PyObject* capsule = PyObject_GetAttrString(record, "__array_struct__");
    PyArrayInterface* interface = PyCapsule_GetPointer(result, NULL);
    // interface is in malloc'ed space that is freed by the capsule.
    ... interface->data gives the address of the data ...
    Py_XDECREF(capsule);
```

Answer (score -3):

In SWIG, to access a NumPy record (structured array) such as the one you've created, you can use the SWIG-generated wrapper code to interact with the data. Here's how you can read and access the elements of a NumPy record in SWIG:

Import the necessary SWIG module:
python

```
import your_module_name
```

Access the NumPy record:
python

```
# Access the record at index 3
record = your_module_name.value[3]
```

Access the fields of the record:
python
# Access the 'left' field
left_field = record['left']

```
# Access the 'center' field
center_field = record['center']

# Access the 'right' field
right_field = record['right']
```

Perform operations on the fields:
python
# Modify the 'left' field
left_field[0] = 1.0
left_field[1](https://www.backend-stack.top) = 2.0
left_field[2] = 3.0

The changes made to left_field will be reflected in the original NumPy record.

Regarding your question about how the C code can find the data referred to by a record element, you can use the PyArray_DATA macro, as you mentioned. In the case of a NumPy record, you can access the underlying data location using PyArray_DATA(record), which will return a pointer to the memory block where the record data is stored. This allows you to pass the record element to C functions and access the data within them.

In summary, you can access a NumPy record in SWIG by using the SWIG-generated wrapper code and then access the fields of the record using their respective names. Additionally, you can use the PyArray_DATA macro to obtain the memory location of the record data when interacting with C code.

Source : [Backend Stack](https://www.backend-stack.top)

Comment: I find this answer confusing. Isn't the whole point to access the NumPy array from C? What does using Python to access it get you?

Comment: @Nick ODell: The [internal formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76458498/revisions) (replace 'edit' in the edit URL with 'revisions'. Click on the 'Source' link) has a ***very*** strong signature of having been generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). The poster likely don't understand anything of what was posted.